# Installing doMPI package in R for MAC

Tags: r

I need help installing a parallel backend called "doMPI" in RStudio. I am simply trying to use an example in the pomp package and it required me to install this particular package. I do the usual `install.packages("doMPI")` but I get a prompt asking whether I want to install from sources as you can see below. I said yes but the library does not load. I am using a MAC for this.

```
> install.packages("doMPI")
also installing the dependency ‘Rmpi’

Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rmpi’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
y/n: y
installing the source packages ‘Rmpi’, ‘doMPI’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rmpi_0.6-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 105181 bytes (102 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 102 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/doMPI_0.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 223374 bytes (218 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 218 KB

* installing *source* package ‘Rmpi’ ...
** package ‘Rmpi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... 
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking mpi.h usability... no
checking mpi.h presence... no
checking for mpi.h... no
configure: error: "Cannot find mpi.h header file"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rmpi’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rmpi’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rmpi’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘Rmpi’ is not available for package ‘doMPI’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/doMPI’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘doMPI’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in


 ‘/private/var/folders/xb/n20n792n5zn0xpyhpdcn4chm0000gn/T/RtmpADdtwf/downloaded_packages’
> library(doMPI)
Error in library(doMPI) : there is no package called ‘doMPI’
```

Comment: Try hitting 'no' when asked if you want to install from source.

Comment: @GauravBansal mm it did not work. It says "doMPI has zero exit status". The error was "There is no packages RMPI". When I tried to install RMPI, I get the same prompt about installing from source and I get "RMPI has zero exit status" when I hit no.

Comment: No sure what it means, but the error is here "configure: error: "Cannot find mpi.h header file."

Comment: @mmm... something has to be missing.. and it has to do with some C-level stuff..

Comment: I was able to install the package successfully without any prompting asking about installing from source.